# Reasons for directions of surface tension components at point of contact

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

I'm a high-schooler currently studying fluid mechanics so please try to explain any answer of yours in comparatively simple words. I'm now going through surface tensions when the angle of contact is acute and obtuse. I've been having trouble trying to understand the reason behind the direction of surface tensions in the liquid-air interface in both scenarios, and the direction of the surface tension in the solid-air interface in the obtuse scenario. The only logic I can think of for solid-air surface tension for an obtuse contact angle explains the opposite direction. It goes: since the cohesive force of the liquid is higher than that of air, the surface film of the solid gets denser in the section directly beneath the liquid, so the surface tension should be in the opposite direction, i.e., towards the section underneath the liquid droplet. Please help me as I cannot find a satisfactory answer from any source I've consulted so far. For reference, [here's the link](https://www.learnatnoon.com/s/in//wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2021/09/oie_uO4vw7VUVkeQ-1-272x300.png) to the diagrams for both scenarios. Thanks!